# Ionic app name multi language

Tags: ionic-framework, internationalization, globalization

I'm using Ionic franmework to develop an app for ios and android.
I'm using this code for multi language in the app:

```
if (typeof navigator.globalization !== "undefined") {
    navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(function (language) {
      var languageValue = (language.value).split("-")[0];
      if (languageValue == 'fr') {
        languageValue = 'fr_FR';
        $rootScope.language = 'fr';
        moment.locale('fr');
      } else {
        languageValue = 'en_US';
        $rootScope.language = 'en';
        moment.locale('en-ca');
      }
      $translate.use(languageValue).then(function (data) {
        console.log("Using locale: " + data);
      }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error using locale: " + error);
      });
    }, null);
  }
```

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
  prefix: 'js/locales/locale-',
  suffix: '.json'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
```

It work perfectly in my app with france and english.
I want the app name also display in English or France depend on globalization too, please give me some advise.

Comment: " I want the app name also display in English or France" , where do u want to display ?

Comment: The app name under the app icon in the device screen

Comment: you need to change app name in config.xml in your ionic project root directory